# Trigger - Can you conditionally execute depending on columns set in the transaction?

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle11g

Is it control trigger to only set a value if a column is not specified in the update statement? For example, if I execute following update statement on a table/column -

```
update sampleTable set firstname='test', lastname='me' where id='id1';
```

In above case, since both firstname and lastname columns are updated, I would not like before update trigger to do anything. However, if following statement is executed -

```
update sampleTable set firstname='test' where id='id1';
```

In above case, since lastname column is not updated, I would like trigger to set lastname to null.

I tried following -

```
Create or Replace Trigger testTrigger before update of firstname on sampleTable for each row
begin
   if :old.firstname != :new.firstname and :old.lastname = :new.lastname then
      :new.lastname = null;
   end if;
end;
```

The idea behind this was that if I would execute the first update statement above, and the new lastname is different from the previous value of last name, it will have different values for :old and :new and hence the if condition won't satisfy and lastname won't get set to null. Of course I was wrong, and in both the update statements it still ends up updating lastname to null.

What are my options here? I am using Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `lastname` set to null if the update statement does not reference  this column, then you can use the `UPDATING()` function.

```
Create or Replace Trigger testTrigger 
before update of firstname on sampleTable 
for each row
begin
   if not updating('LASTNAME') then
      :new.lastname := null;
   end if;
end;
/
```